# postgres - generating documents for full text search taking forever and eating up disk space

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

We use PostgreSQL and Django-Haystack with Elasticsearch for search on our service, and were thinking of switching to Postgres's built in full text search because of various annoyances using a NoSQL search solution to handle our highly relational data. Basically we use a tag system, and there are 5 tables(tag, creator, studio, character, channel), with a many to many relationship on the series table, and we want series to be searchable on all this data. Title is just a regular column on series. This is what we are running to try and make our initial documents for full text search(our tables were generated with django ORM so sorry if it looks like they were named by an imbecile).

```
     SELECT to_tsvector(shows_series.title) || 
       to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(shows_tag.name, ' ')), '')) ||
       to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(shows_creator.name, ' ')), '')) ||
       to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(shows_studio.name, ' ')), '')) ||
       to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(shows_channel.name, ' ')), '')) ||
       to_tsvector(coalesce((string_agg(shows_character.name, ' ')), '')) as document
FROM shows_series
JOIN shows_series_tags ON shows_series_tags.series_id = shows_series_tags.tag_id
JOIN shows_tag ON shows_tag.id = shows_series_tags.tag_id
JOIN shows_series_creators ON shows_series_creators.series_id = shows_series_creators.creator_id
JOIN shows_creator ON shows_creator.id = shows_series_creators.creator_id
JOIN shows_series_studios ON shows_series_studios.series_id = shows_series_studios.studio_id
JOIN shows_studio ON shows_studio.id = shows_series_studios.studio_id
JOIN shows_series_channels ON shows_series_channels.series_id = shows_series_channels.channel_id
JOIN shows_channel ON shows_channel.id = shows_series_channels.channel_id
JOIN shows_series_characters ON shows_series_characters.series_id = shows_series_characters.character_id
JOIN shows_character ON shows_character.id = shows_series_characters.character_id
GROUP BY shows_series.id;
```

This is taking forever to run(still going as I type this and has been running for 2 hours), and ate up about 200GB of disk space last I checked, had to kill it on a mac laptop because the disk was becoming full and run it on a 2TB machine. Not one of the tables involved in this has more than a few hundred thousand rows, and the actual size of the database is under 1GB. Generating the documents with Elasticsearch(which is still taking its data out of the db) took about a half hour and there were no problems with disk space. Are we doing something wrong here, or is this normal?

EDIT: Updated with EXPLAIN (http://explain.depesz.com/s/De7g):

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=53120969839553.67..53978180310279.34 rows=109608 width=127)
   ->  Sort  (cost=53120969839553.67..53243428477445.85 rows=48983455156873 width=127)
         Sort Key: shows_series.id
         ->  Merge Join  (cost=6.65..629070782293.36 rows=48983455156873 width=127)
               Merge Cond: (shows_channel.id = shows_series_channel.series_id)
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..2034.38 rows=119856 width=31)
                     ->  Index Scan using shows_channel_pkey on shows_channel  (cost=0.28..73.52 rows=1816 width=19)
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.70..462.82 rows=66 width=12)
                           ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.70..462.49 rows=66 width=12)
                                 Merge Cond: (shows_series_characters.series_id = shows_character.id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using shows_series_characters_series_id on shows_series_characters  (cost=0.42..3635.72 rows=534 width=8)
                                       Filter: (series_id = character_id)
                                 ->  Index Scan using shows_character_pkey on shows_character  (cost=0.28..189.44 rows=5277 width=16)
               ->  Materialize  (cost=3.08..590099807642.18 rows=23252632396170 width=108)
                     ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.08..531968226651.76 rows=23252632396170 width=108)
                           ->  Index Scan using shows_series_channel_series_id on shows_series_channel  (cost=0.29..2597.25 rows=382 width=8)
                                 Filter: (series_id = channel_id)
                           ->  Merge Join  (cost=2.79..783879319.61 rows=60870765435 width=100)
                                 Merge Cond: (shows_creator.id = shows_series_creators.series_id)
                                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.90..6185.28 rows=427224 width=27)
                                       ->  Index Scan using shows_creator_pkey on shows_creator  (cost=0.29..347.87 rows=10172 width=15)
                                       ->  Materialize  (cost=0.61..497.22 rows=42 width=12)
                                             ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.61..497.01 rows=42 width=12)
                                                   Merge Cond: (shows_series_studios.series_id = shows_studio.id)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using shows_series_studios_series_id on shows_series_studios  (cost=0.29..2692.15 rows=396 width=8)
                                                         Filter: (series_id = studio_id)
                                                   ->  Index Scan using shows_studio_pkey on shows_studio  (cost=0.28..272.86 rows=7772 width=16)
                                 ->  Materialize  (cost=1.18..162959957.46 rows=6210583040 width=85)
                                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.18..147433499.86 rows=6210583040 width=85)
                                             ->  Index Scan using shows_series_creators_series_id on shows_series_creators  (cost=0.42..5673.03 rows=835 width=8)
                                                   Filter: (series_id = creator_id)
                                             ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.76..102182.03 rows=7437824 width=77)
                                                   ->  Seq Scan on shows_series  (cost=0.00..4971.08 rows=109608 width=67)
                                                   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.76..4044.32 rows=68 width=10)
                                                         ->  Merge Join  (cost=0.76..4043.98 rows=68 width=10)
                                                               Merge Cond: (shows_series_tags.series_id = shows_tag.id)
                                                               ->  Index Scan using shows_series_tags_series_id on shows_series_tags  (cost=0.42..22317.27 rows=3292 width=8)
                                                                     Filter: (series_id = tag_id)
                                                               ->  Index Scan using shows_tag_pkey on shows_tag  (cost=0.28..78.89 rows=1408 width=14)
```

Comment: Can you show an `EXPLAIN` for this query please? Also, please enable `log_temp_files = 0` and see if it reports tempfile creation.

Comment: It still hasn't given me any prompt or anything to indicate that it is done, its just hanging.

Comment: hahaha, that's the biggest `cost` estimate I've seen in a while, `53120969839553`. Costs aren't directly equivalent to any time estimate, they're abstract units, but ... lets just say that a cost of 10^13 means PostgreSQL doesn't expect to be done any time soon. Odd, as it's a relatively simple query. How big are these tables (row counts)? Are the stats accurate - is autovacuum enabled? If you run `ANALYZE` does it make any difference? What's `random_page_cost`, `seq_page_cost`, `effective_cache_size` and `shared_buffers` set to? If you `SET work_mem = '100MB'` and rerun does it help?

Comment: the largest table involved in that query contains around 658000 rows. I just turned autovacuum on and set the work memory to 1000mb(I have 16gb of ram on here), otherwise the values asked for are reflected in the default config file [here](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/backend/utils/misc/postgresql.conf.sample;h=a3880da7dac5d8ff55dc8f5f7a3f1fc8052627b0;hb=REL9_0_STABLE)
Running EXPLAIN again shows: GroupAggregate  (cost=16729161964954.48..17521343324653.89 rows=109608 width=127)